# images upload of any user in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

first and parent "register"
[image: register]

and second is

[image: userimg]

[image: error on Query]

What I wanted is to create a script in which one User with unique `SN` whenever upload a pic that pic path save in "userimg" i user SN as foreign key in userimg

code is below

```
if(isset($_POST['SN']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES['upload_image']['name'].$user_SN;
    $filesize = $_FILES['upload_image']['size'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['upload_image']['type'];    
    $target_path ="uploads/". basename( $filename );

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_image']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
    {
        $result = $target_path ;
        $sql="INSERT INTO userimg (src, size, type,SN ) VALUES ('".$result."', '".$filesize."','".$filetype."','".$user_SN."')";
        echo $sql." ";
        echo $filesize." ";
        echo $filetype." ";
        $inst=mysql_query($sql);

        if (!$inst)
        {   
            print "error";
        }
    }
}
```

This script is working for one picture but what I want is like multiple uploads (just like a gallery) by user and saving that path in my second table.

Do I need to create a userimg table for each SN means user? What am I missing?

[EDIT]

Problem solved. Mistake was Making SN in userimg a unique and i rename image like this(code is below ) - Thankx Tuhin!

```
if(isset($_POST['SN']))
{
    $filename = $_FILES['upload_image']['name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['upload_image']['size'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['upload_image']['type'];
    $timeSt = time();
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $name = $info['filename'];
    $format = $info['extension'];
    $target_path ="uploads/".basename( $name )."_".$user_SN."_".$timeSt.".".$format;
}
```

Comment: I think its fine unless you upload same image name for same user. You can rename the uploaded image concatenating timestamp with image name.

Comment: Unless you upload same image name for same user ? means different image name right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same user (means same SN value) tries to upload the same image (means already uploaded by him with same image name in this app) then the 'src' column in the second table will be same. Also if the uploaded folder first image file will be replaced by the newer file. Thats why I proposed you to add time stamp and rename the uploaded image file and store it into the DB.

Comment: i used another file(with different )name  but it is not uploading/ i used INSERT STATEMENT IN mysql Query..instead UPDATE due to my requirement is making user images (gallery)/ i really need to Understand what is missing./ Sir DO You still Thinks My tables are  fine to create a user gallery (having many images for one user Ok let say 3-5 images )/then why I am failing to Insert another query in that child table(userimg)(reason what i am understanding Query cant FIND Place to INSERT)What you think sir ?

Comment: After the insert query line just echo $sql . Now paste the query here or you can try yourself to run that query in phpmysql query box and see what the errors are.

Comment: In second table is SN should not be unique. Also rename the image like  logo_100_1385656179.gif i.e add timestamp before the image extension other wise it will not be an image file.